# Web page request be aborted in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, firebug

I have created a `ASP.NET web application` and host in IIS ,But there is a `aborted` message on firebug status column when access the web page .Why?

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116641/how-to-solve-firebugs-aborted-messages-upon-ajax-requests go through http://blog.haraldkraft.de/2011/12/firebugs-aborted-message-upon-ajax-request/

Comment: @d.Siva-Thanks,But in my web page no ajax request!